# How Sanjay heard Bhagwad Gita?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, bhagavad-gita, arjuna, pandavas

As we all know that Bhagwad Gita was told to Arjuna by Krishna in kurushetra.  At that time, many people were also present there.

Many scholars/people explain  that Krishna paused the time when he was narrating Gita to Arjuna. Apart from  Arjuna, **Dhritrashtra** and **Sanjay** also heard Gita.

Now  I have some questions.

**1.Why Bhisma, Karna and others did not hear Gita even they were also present there?**

**2.If time was paused, how Sanjay heard Gita?**

**3.Is there any reference in Mahabharata or Gita, which proves that Krishna paused the time?**

Comment: Time cant be paused, it got dilated in reality, but appeared to be paused in layman's terms and from earth's reference. https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/36340/16530 Sanjay heard Gita because of boon of Vyasa regardless of time dilation just like one with a link will eventually watch a full movie regardless of slow or fast buffering.

Comment: That's why I asked that if there is any scriptural reference of it or not @Manu Kumar

Comment: Puranas dont spoon feed everything and every detail else it will become too complicated for comprehension of a common man to understand and diverting the true purpose of scriptures that is spirituality, time dilation was unknown 2-3 centuries back but is a universal principle just like gravitation and electromagnetism. Part of Ashta https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siddhi of Creator God.

Comment: Good question. A precursory question was asked by me long back.@Harshit Gangwar

Comment: My earlier question was [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9209/3869) @Harshit Gangwar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The questions are:

> 1.Why Bhisma, Karna and others did not hear Gita even they were also present there?
>
> 2.If time was paused, how Sanjay heard Gita?
>
> 3.Is there any reference in Mahabharata or Gita, which proves that Krishna paused the time?

An interesting question indeed!!

---

There are 2 options available , in my opinion, to answer these questions.

1. ***There was no lengthy discourse***, which was popularised in the name of Gita. It might be an **interpolation**.

Sri Krishna might have sternly warned Arjuna of consequences of renunciation of war, by abdicating the duty of a warrior, in quick and yet brief speech.  Arjuna might have reconciled.

2. Sri Krishna might have stopped the time.

If we accept that Sri Krishna stopped the TIME, as at the time of giving discourse to Arjuna, his mind had been merged into the BRAHMAN and thus he was BRAHMAN/TIME itself, then the question as to **how could Sanjay hear Gita**? is genuine.

---

Sage Vyasa [gives power to Sanjaya](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m06/m06002.htm) to witness the Mahabharata war to report to Dhritarashtra.

> "Upon his not wishing to see the battle but wishing to hear of it,
>   Vyasa, that lord of boons, gave a boon to Sanjaya. (And addressing
>   Dhritarashtra he said),--
>
> 'This Sanjaya, O king, will describe the battle to thee. **Nothing in
>   the whole battle will be beyond this one's eyes.**
>
> ' Endued, O king with ***celestial vision***, Sanjaya will narrate the
>   battle to thee. ***He will have knowledge of everything. Manifest or
>   concealed***, (happening) by day or by night, even that which is
>   thought of in the mind, Sanjaya shall know everything. Weapons will
>   not cut him and exertion will not fatigue him. This son of Gavalgani
>   will come out of the battle with life. "

---

So nothing is concealed, whatever transpired in the Mahabharata war, from Sanjaya.  That was how he could listen to Gita also.