# Shouldn't there be time dilation when Riksharaja took Vali and Sugriva to Brahma lok?

Tags: ramayana, brahma, lokas, vali, sugriva

We know at least two incidents where individuals experienced [time dilation](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2789/time-travel-in-hindu-scripture) as per our scriptures - 1) King Kakudmi traveling to Brahma lok with his daughter Princess Revati 2) King Muchukunda fighting on the side of Devas against Asura

The third incident is indirect - Arjuna [travel](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9635/how-many-years-was-arjuna-in-svarga) to Swarga lok before the war

However there seems to be another incident which takes place as per Uttara Kanda of Ramayana , where time dilation should have taken place. This was when Riksharaja [took](https://archive.org/details/TheRamayanaUttaraKandam/page/n153/mode/2up) his new born sons Vali and Sugriva to Brahma lok after their birth. There Brahma consoled him and asked him to become king of vanaras at Kishkindha

> Thereupon taking them, he came to the abode of Brahma. 
>   Beholding his son Riksharaja with Ins sons, Brahma, the 
>   grand-father of the celestials, consoled him in diverse ways.
>   ......
>
> ......Brahma, having said this, the 
>   celestial emissary, with Riksharaja before him, proceeded to 
>   the highly picturesque city of Kishkinda. And having 
>   entered there with the velocity of the wind, he, at the command of the Patriarch, crowned the leading monkey Riksharaja as king;

It is clear from above that it was Riksharaja visiting Lord Brahma and not the other way around. From Princess Revati's example we know that 27 chatur yugas had elapsed when she was in Brahma Loka. But why don't we see something similar in Riksharaja's case ? Is it because Uttara Kanda of Ramayana is an [interpolation](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/20933/is-the-uttara-kanda-of-the-srimad-valmiki-ramayana-interpolated) ?

Comment: You forgot the third example of Krishna versus Brahma.

Comment: @Wikash_ - can you point out that incident ? I can't seem to place it. Thanks

Comment: Maybe as I have not studied Ramayana yet. Time dilation is needed for untrained souls, thats why Brahma does not keep his offsprings and creation at the same realm as his, rather on dilated 13 below realms as time of 1 life of mukta Brahma becomes equivalent to infinite births of unenlightened jivatamas and their play in worldly Maya. 1 day of 5th Swarga loka is 1 year of 7th Earth, most probably similar is relation between 3rd and 5th realm and 1st Brahma loka to 3rd realm as its most seems to be recursive stacked creation.

Comment: So roughly 1 year on 7th earth is 1 day on 5th Swarga and 1 hour/muhurata on 3rd realm and 1minute/seconds on Brahma loka. http://bhagavata.org/canto10/chapter13.html Similar, time dilation is mentioned when Brahma tested Krishna as mentioned is Bhagvatam.